# How to save document in office 365 sharepoint 2013 site from microsoft word 2013 addin with seamless authentication?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, office365

I want to save the Microsoft word document 2013 in office 365 site from the word addin and i successfully saved the document in the office 365 SharePoint site library,

but i have to bypass the login credentials popup and i want to do it with the c# code from my addin. like i have to give the credentials from the code so that it will not open credential popup.

please refer the image.

[word addin](http://imgur.com/HqcuXYM)[1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking questions in the [help]. You can use the [edit] link below your question to include the code you're using to do the save and upload an image that can be used on this site.

Comment: Did you realize that you can achieve this with File->Save As -> Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to save it to Sharepoint 2013 site, you can save all the trouble by going for File -> Save As -> Sharepoint.

Don't mean to reinvent the wheel, but if you want to do this programatically with Addin, after you get authenticated with Sharepoint, you'll get an access token.
You'll be good to go to use the token to save file to sharepoint before it expires. Just check if the token expires before actually showing the authentication pop-up.

Comment: but there is no way i can pass credentials in the save method

Comment: and i don't want to save it from converting it in bytes, i want to do it like when the document is save in offfice 365 and when user again edit the document he/she press cntrl + s and document directly save in site.. this is seamless authentication